# Send key to a flash application

Tags: c#, flash

I have to send some key to a flash application via C#, I have simple tried

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}");
```

It's working everywhere, except flash application. How to send key via C#, which will be detected by flash?

Comment: It works for me even with DirectX applications. Cant imagine why.

Comment: Have you tried with flash?

Comment: no.. But it must be working with flash. How did you check this ?

Comment: I opened flash application in browser, I have focused flash app, so it should work, but it doesn't. Tried Chrome and Opera

Comment: You write this line in a event that checks if you have focused a flash app ?

Comment: No, but i'm sure, because it works when i manually press key.

Comment: I think this line of code runs before you focus the flash application.

Comment: If anyone is interested in - I have noticed that my application started working when I have physically pressing random buttons on keyboard. Anyway, I think that it's browser restrictions, because my application worked to flash app outside them.